# How do I get my nav panel to change color based on the active page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently working on my first solo project out of college for the university's technology department. The home page looks like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3toftjko/).

What I want to happen is the navigation (Home, Contact, etc.) to appear as it does on [hover](/questions/tagged/hover) when the user is on that page.  Short of having a second class or id to denote it on it's respective pages is there another way?

### HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="header">
    <img src="">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">EXTONE</a>
        </li>|
        <li><a href="#">EXTTWO</a>
        </li>|
        <li><a href="#">EXTTHREE</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="news.html">News</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Submit a Ticket</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color: #222;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0026aa, white);
/* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(#0026aa, white);
/* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#0026aa, white);
/* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(#0026aa, white);
/* Standard syntax */
}
body {
padding: 10px;
font: 76%/150%"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Lucida, Verdana,      Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#nav {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: none;
width: 100%;
float: left;
border-bottom: 3px solid #cbcc9d;
}
#nav li {
display: inline;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
#nav a:link, #nav a:visited {
color: #000;
background: #cbcc9d;
padding: 20px 40px 4px 10px;
float: left;
width: auto;
border-right: 1px solid #42432d;
text-decoration: none;
font: bold 1em/1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
#nav a:hover, #nav a:focus {
color: #fff;
background: #727454;
}
#nav li:first-child a {
border-left: 1px solid #42432d;
}
#home #nav-home a, #contact #nav-contact a, #news #nav-news a, #services     #nav-services a {
background: #e35a00;
color: #fff;
text-shadow: none;
}
#home #nav-home a:hover, #contact #nav-contact a:hover, #news #nav-news     a:hover, #services #nav-services a:hover {
background: #e35a00;
}
#nav a:active {
background: #e35a00;
color: #fff;
}
#wrap {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: none;
}
#header {
padding: 5px 10px;
background: none;
padding-top: 25px;
text-align: right;
}
#header li {
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
}
#header li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #cbcc9d;
font-weight: bold;
}    
#header img {
display: block;
float: right;
}
h1 {
margin: 0;
}
#main {
float: left;
width: 530px;
height: 763px;
padding: 10px;
background: white;
border-right: 1px solid #cbcc9d;
}
h2 {
margin: 0 0 1em;
}
#sidebar {
float: right;
width: 350px;
height: 763px;
padding: 10px;
background: white;
padding-right: 4em;
}
#footer {
clear: both;
padding: 5px 10px;
background: #cc9;
}
#footer p {
margin: 0;
}
* html #footer {
height: 1px;
}
#ServicesListCol {
float: left;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
display: block;
width: 530px;
height: 665px;
}
#ServicesListCol h4 {
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 12pt;
text-decoration: none;
}
#ServicesListCol ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 10pt;
font-weight: normal;
}
#LetterNav {
text-align: center;
}
#LetterNav a {
text-decoration: none;
}
a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #0026aa
}
a:visited {
color: #0026aa
}
a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I'm using some JavaScript on later pages and I have a Spry accordion happening on another but I don't know outside the XHTML, CSS3, & JavaScript wheelhouses enough to do it offhand.

Comment: You cannot do this with pure CSS if thats what you're asking (CSS has no way of knowing what page is active). You would have to create a helper class and apply it via javascript. Or just set that active class on the nav item of that page. It depends on what your setup is.

Comment: I kind of assumed that CSS would not be the only way to do it short of creating a separate class that would alter the background color and font colors and apply it to those pages that the user is on.  That is to say, #navSelected { changes } then on the home it would appear as <li><a id=navSelected> etc.

Comment: Do you load you page data via an ajax call or is every page static?

Comment: All are static.  My experience this far is only in creating static content.  I'm hoping over time (but soon) I can learn responsive and more agile methods but this is only a temp gig that my professor (and department head) offered me for two months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) it, and use a selected class that gets applied to the selected item. You didn't say whether or not the menu is being dynamically generated on each page load, or whatever, so I can't advise in more detail about how you'd do that.

Comment: That just sounds awkward _I would KISS it_ :)

Comment: I have each page generated as it shows in JSFiddle.  When I created the holder pages I basically got my index, loaded it with filler text and copied the index.

So the KISS would be, to interpret what you said.  create a #nav.selected that would alter the bg color and font color right?

Comment: Correct. There may be more elegant/dynamic ways to do it based upon the url of the page, but I'm a big fan of keeping things simple.

Comment: I think a combination of this and the Michael Jones answer really helped out.  Thanks all so much.

Answer (score 1):

Now, to make it simple you could just add the corresponding ID to each page. Like this (In example home page is active):

**HTML**

```
<li id="active"><a href="#">Home</a> 
</li>
```

Then you could style the `active` ID for each page. Now that would be the simple and tedious way. That will NOT work though if you are using PHP `include`. If you are using PHP `include` please let me know, because I have a much better way of doing this! :)

Comment: I had not planned on using PHP as the only practice I have had in development outside of self taught HTML/Javascript had focused on CSS in addition to this.  I was under the impression that active only applied when it was clicked and during the duration of said click.

EDIT: Wait I see what you mean, not :active but and actual active... yea I see. Thanks!

Comment: Using PHP isn't required. If you've got a hardcoded menu at the top of each page, just throw the "active" class (or whatever you want to call it) directly into the menu and go from there!